# How to call a method after some specific interval of time in Java

Tags: java, timer

Here is the use case:

I am using Java (with Spring)

Once the user (through a web-app) confirms to the subscription, I want to send him an email exactly after 30 mins.

Now how to do this? Do I need a message broker? or something like ScheduledExecutorService?
Do I need some sort of queue?

Please advise.

Comment: I think a better title could be `"How to send mail, 30 minutes after an event."`

Comment: please send me your code if you have completed my id is manisathasivam@gmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can look into [quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for this.

By the way a common strategy is to send a bulk of all pending mails in bulk in every 30 minutes or so.  Quartz can help in do that as well.

Comment: thanks, but how will this happen actually? Am I right in assuming that at occurance of every event, a new thread will be created which will wait for 30 mins, then sends the mail and then die?

Comment: can we do this using ScheduledExecutorService?

Comment: @adi I am not sure about exact inner workings of Quartz, but rest assured, it is super efficient... I have used it to drive couple of thousands jobs without any significant resource depletion. As far as the specific mailing jobs are concerned... I guess Quartz would do great. 

I never used ScheduledExecutorService, so can't honestly comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). Its fairly easy to use. You can schedule something every week or ever 30 minutes or whatever you want basically.

Answer (score 2):

Create an object for Timer

```
 private Timer myTimer;
```

in main method

```
myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //your method
        }

    }, 0, 200);
```

Comment: Good answer. Day saved.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that the thread will die after sending the mail. When you configure Quartz, a new thread will automatically be created and will execute the assigned task on specified interval. Or else you use Timer class also. It is very easy to use.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(); // Get timer

    long delay = 30 * 60 * 1000; // 3o min delay

    // Schedule the two timers to run with different delays.
    timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 0, delay);

...................



class MyTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        // business logic
        // send mail here
    }
}
```

Comment: what will happen to the thread if it is not dead after sending the mail? will I have hundreds on threads after a while?

Comment: A separate thread will be running and when time ticks Task will gets executed. When you create a timer and it is scheduled, it runs in the background and executes the task every after specified interval. Try the following example 

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  long delay = 1000; // 1 sec delay
  timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 0, delay);
  
  while(true){
   
  }
 }
}

public class MyTask extends TimerTask {

 public void run() {
     // business logic
     System.out.println("Mail sent");
 }
}

Comment: that works well but what about if I need to change times? For instance, I want delay time to be in the range of two time.